# MariaDB writing transaction and rollback - novice

Tags: mysql, mariadb, transaction, rollback, mariadb-10.6

Currently I am learning how to write transactions for MariaDB (I got a version 10.6 running).
I attempt to execute several commands and based on their success to commit or rollback.

So far I have searched google for a few days and got really stuck not knowing how to go about it.
This is how far I got and cannot figure out what is wrong.
I am very grateful for any pointers!

Cheers
JR

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FWtest`.`testtrans`;
CREATE TABLE `FWtest`.`testtrans` ( 
    `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
    `ver` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
    `name` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
    `savedatetime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `FWtest`.`testtrans2`;
CREATE TABLE `FWtest`.`testtrans2` ( 
    `ID` INT NOT NULL , 
    `param1` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL , 
    `param2` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



DELIMITER |
START TRANSACTION
    BEGIN NOT ATOMIC TRY;
        SET @config_name='test';
        -- get the next version number, set 0 if none
        SELECT @config_version:= IFNULL(max(`ver`)+1,0) FROM `FWtest`.`testtrans` WHERE `name` = @config_name;
        INSERT INTO `FWtest`.`testtrans`(`name`, `ver`, `savedatetime`) 
          VALUES ( @config_name, @config_version, NOW() );
        
        SELECT @config_id:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
        
        INSERT INTO `FWtest`.`testtrans2`(`ID`, `param1`, `param2`) 
          VALUES 
            (@config_id, 1, null),
            (@config_id, 2, 'aa');  -- this line will make the insert fail
        
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK;
    END CATCH
COMMIT|
DELIMITER ;
```

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to the pointers of Akina I worked out a solution using an exception handler directly in a transaction:

```
DELIMITER |
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
    START TRANSACTION;
            SET @config_name='test';
            SELECT @config_version:= IFNULL(max(`ver`)+1,0) FROM `FWtest`.`testtrans` WHERE `name` = @config_name;
            INSERT INTO `FWtest`.`testtrans`(`name`, `ver`, `savedatetime`) VALUES ( @config_name, @config_version, NOW() );
            
            SELECT @config_id:=LAST_INSERT_ID();
            
            INSERT INTO `FWtest`.`testtrans2`
            (`ID`, `param1`, `param2`) 
            VALUES 
              (@config_id, 1, null),
              (@config_id, 2, 'nn');    -- this line will make the insert fail
            
    
    COMMIT;
END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Note: When using this sample code in a sql tool (e.g. DBeaver) then error checking and rollback needs to be turned off in order for the transaction to handle the error itself.

Comment: Where you have found TRY-CATCH syntax in MariaDB? I cannot find any words about it in the documentation..

Comment: I found it as examples on various forums. You are right I did not check it against the MariaDB docu. Is there some kind of equivalent in MariaDB for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @JeanRandhahn - SQL syntax varies widely.  For MariaDB, trust only MariaDB examples, Trust, but with caution, MySQL examples, since they are usually keep up with either, but with a lag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiny sample:

Create test table with CHECK constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT CHECK (id < 100)) SELECT 1 id UNION SELECT 11;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 11 |

Create stored procedure with the transaction and error handling:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test (value1 INT, value2 INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK; -- if an error occures then rollback
START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (value1);
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (value2);
COMMIT;
END
```

Call SP with valid parameters:

```
CALL test (2, 22); -- valid parameters, inserts will be committed
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 11 |
| 2 |
| 22 |

Call SP with invalid parameters:

```
CALL test (3, 333); -- invalid parameters, inserts will be rollbacked
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 11 |
| 2 |
| 22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hP9aYHhX)

Comment: Does it have to be in a stored procedure? I need to pass lots of data to insert and as far as I know I cannot pass much and as array to a procedure!?
For what is the CHECK constraint good?

Comment: Compound statement needed for handler declaration. But you may, of course, execute the transaction statements interactively and check for each statement execution success visually.

Comment: *as far as I know I cannot pass much and as array to a procedure* Your knowledge is not correct. You may provide serialized data array as solid SP parameter then parse it in SP and insert row-by-row in a cycle.

Comment: Note that the "3" was rolled back because of the "333".

Comment: If you try to pass a large array in, it is probably better to populate a table, then you can use the power of SQL, not the clumsiness of SQL's string manipulation functions.

Comment: True. Temptable with some predefined name and structure is good option.